# Integrate $\int \frac {dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-49}}\,$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to integrate the following:

$$\int \frac {dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-49}}\,$$

using the substitution $x=7\cosh(t)$

This is as far as I've gotten:

$\int \frac {dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-49}}\,$ = $\int \frac {7\sinh(t)dt}{7\cosh(t)7\sinh(t)}\,$ = $\int \frac {dt}{7\cosh(t)}\,$ = $\int \frac {\cosh(t)dt}{7\cosh^2(t)}\,$ = $\int \frac {\cosh(t)dt}{7(1+\sinh^2(t))}\,$

Let $u=\sinh(t)$, $du=\cosh(t)dt$

$$\int \frac {\cosh(t)dt}{7(1+\sinh^2(t))}\,
=\int \frac {du}{7(1+u^2)}\,$$ 
$$=\frac {1}{7}\arctan(u)+C=\frac{1}{7} \arctan(\sinh(t))+C$$

This is as far as I have been able to get. Somehow from here I need to get to

$$-\frac{1}{7} \arctan(\frac{7}{\sqrt{x^2-49}})+C$$

Can someone please show me how to finish this integration problem off? I would appreciate it so so much.

Comment: Another change: consider $t=\sqrt{x^2-49}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606590/integrate-int-frac-sqrt9-4x2xdx/1606669#1606669

Comment: Yet another substitution: $t = 7 \sec \theta$. I think the reason that OP uses hyperbolic functions is because the question says so.

Answer (score 3):

Note

\begin{align}
&\ \frac{1}{7} \arctan(\sinh t)\\
=&\ \frac{1}{7} \arctan\sqrt{\cosh^2t -1}
=\frac{1}{7} \arctan\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{49}-1}\\
=&\ \frac{1}{7} \arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}7
 = \frac{1}{7}(\frac\pi2-  \text{arctan} \frac7{\sqrt{x^2-49}})\\
 =&\ - \frac{1}{7}\text{arctan} \frac7{\sqrt{x^2-49}}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to make the substitution $x=7 \sec u$ in the original quesion. Then all that remains is to integrate $\frac{1}{7}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\cosh^2 t - \sinh^2 t =1$ so $\sinh t = \sqrt{\cosh^2 t- 1}$.

Then refer back to the substitution $x = 7 \cosh t$.